# How can I make vegan cream cheese using potatoes?

Tags: dairy-substitutes, recipe-request

I want to make vegan cream cheese using mashed or blender blended potatoes, but I can't find a recipe for it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hmm maybe you haven't found a recipe for that because potatoes are not much good for making vegan cream cheese? Do you have some reason to think this will work? I can make a sort of cheesy sauce with potatoes, cashew butter and yeast products, but cream cheese, not so much. Almonds make good cream cheese.

Comment: saw a vid on using potatoes for sour cream I figured why not cream cheese.

Answer (score 4):

To make a creamy cheese-like substance I use this recipe:
Peel and boil together  1 potato, 1 carrot and 1 onion until soft.
Keep the cook water, amount used depends on how much cheese you want and how viscous.
Put cooked ingredients with water into a blender.
Add nutritional yeast, curcuma for colour, perhaps some miso paste.
Blend again when hot. It's ready to pour hot or can be used later.
I use this over vegetables or in vegan lasagnes.
The nutritional value can be enhanced by blending in unsweetened soy protein powder, or a 2:1 pea:rice protein powder mix.